# Grafana Change Metric Dynamically

Tags: grafana, promql, prometheus-operator, grafana-variable

I'm using prometheus and grafana. I wanted to change the metric based on the Source as a variable.
so If the source is source1 then I want the first metric else the second metric

```
src1_request1_counter1{job='$job', instance=~"localhost:8080"} 

src2_request2_counter2{job='$job', instance=~"localhost:9090"}
```

Thanks In Advance
Rake

Answer (score 1):

so I figured out two ways to do it ,I am a Posting it as it might help others
1)Use an Or Condition in the query

```
rate(src1_request1_counter1{job="$application", 
instance="$instance"}[1m]) or 
rate(src2_request2_counter2{job="$application", 
instance="$instance"}[1m])
```

2) Use Variables Ref:-
[Dynamically change the metric name in prometheus in grafana dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61436851/dynamically-change-the-metric-name-in-prometheus-in-grafana-dashboard/61885293?noredirect=1#comment109604233_61885293)

FYI , I used the first option as it was simpler in my case